# how can i use "+" and "," for category_name in WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

i want my category_name to be like => "music" and "new" or "music" and "old" , to show the posts
width the category ( "music" and "new" ) or ( "music" and "old" ).

i've try the code below but didn't work :

```
$song = array(
   "category_name" => "music+new,old",
);
$recent = new WP_Query( $song );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 different queries in one - combination. But category_name parameter can't understand this.
For such non-simple combinations you can use taxonomy queries.

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'music' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'new','old' ),
    ), 
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For more example you can check taxonomy code examples in [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters).